# Modify an existing excel with all columns word wrap property to false

Tags: c#, excel, ssrs-2008, word-wrap

I have an issue with my SSRS reports while exporting to excell. The columns are set to word wrap automatically. I searched for this and I did't get any solution and I want to alter the excel file without word wrap ad save it when it creates. Can anyone help me on this or is there any alternate method for this?

regards,

Sivajith

Comment: It will not be that easy.. Wrapping property is a part of styling of the excel cell .. How do you generate the excel sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you can manually remove the wrap by highlighting the entire table and going to the home tab. It'll be mid screen and say "wrap text." Sometimes you have to click it twice to undo the wrap, this is an updating issue that I've really only had occur in large tables. That is the simplest way to fix your problem without getting into SSRS exporting.